# Cause: invalid type code: 1C for android studio gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Android studio working fine but after update the plugin I am getting below error. I tried updating the JDK and reinstall the Android Studio but still facing the same error.

This is sync tab error.

```
Cause: invalid type code: 1C
```

This is the build tab error

```
   020-06-04 19:13:09,207 [1650474]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Android Studio 4.0  Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223 
2020-06-04 19:13:09,207 [1650474]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2020-06-04 19:13:09,207 [1650474]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - OS: Windows 10 
2020-06-04 19:13:09,207 [1650474]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Plugin to blame: CSV Plugin version: 2.11.1 
2020-06-04 19:13:09,208 [1650475]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv.CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 [Plugin: net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:223)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:167)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getImplementationClass(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.createInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapter(ExtensionPointImpl.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapter(ExtensionPointImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.access$100(ExtensionPointImpl.java:33)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl$1.next(ExtensionPointImpl.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionProcessingHelper.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionProcessingHelper.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionPointName.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.getFileTypeByFile(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:742)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.getFileTypeByFile(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFile.getFileType(VirtualFile.java:328)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.<init>(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:59)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiFileFactoryImpl.trySetupPsiForFile(PsiFileFactoryImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiFileFactoryImpl.createFileFromText(PsiFileFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiFileFactoryImpl.createFileFromText(PsiFileFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementFactoryImpl.createDummyFile(GroovyPsiElementFactoryImpl.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementFactoryImpl.createGroovyFile(GroovyPsiElementFactoryImpl.java:621)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.impl.GroovyPsiElementFactoryImpl.createExpressionFromText(GroovyPsiElementFactoryImpl.java:169)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.lang.psi.GroovyPsiElementFactory.createExpressionFromText(GroovyPsiElementFactory.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslUtil.createLiteral(GroovyDslUtil.java:375)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.groovy.GroovyDslParser.convertToPsiElement(GroovyDslParser.java:147)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.FakeElement.lambda$createPsiElement$0(FakeElement.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:807)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.FakeElement.createPsiElement(FakeElement.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.FakeElement.produceValue(FakeElement.java:118)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.CachedValue.updateValue(CachedValue.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.CachedValue.getValue(CachedValue.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSimpleExpression.getValue(GradleDslSimpleExpression.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.GradlePropertyModelImpl.extractAndGetValueType(GradlePropertyModelImpl.java:523)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.GradlePropertyModelImpl.getValueType(GradlePropertyModelImpl.java:108)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.PropertyUtil.resolveModel(PropertyUtil.java:130)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.resolveModel(ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.java:245)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.model.ext.ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.toString(ResolvedPropertyModelImpl.java:168)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.android.PsDeclaredLibraryAndroidDependency.getSpec(PsLibraryAndroidDependency.kt:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.PsDeclaredLibraryDependency$DefaultImpls.toKey(PsLibraryDependency.kt:36)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.android.PsDeclaredLibraryAndroidDependency.toKey(PsLibraryAndroidDependency.kt:43)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.PsDeclaredDependencyCollection.refreshParsedDependencies(PsDependencyCollection.kt:176)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.PsDeclaredDependencyCollection.refresh(PsDependencyCollection.kt:171)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.android.PsAndroidModule.init(PsAndroidModule.kt:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.PsModuleCollection.update(PsModuleCollection.kt:110)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.PsModuleCollection.update(PsModuleCollection.kt:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.android.PsCollectionBase.refresh(PsCollectionBase.kt:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.model.PsProjectImpl.applyChanges(PsProjectImpl.kt:111)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.PsContextImpl.applyChanges(PsContextImpl.kt:218)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.configurables.ProjectPerspectiveConfigurable.apply(ProjectPerspectiveConfigurable.kt:49)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.apply(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:384)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.apply(ConfigurableEditor.java:324)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.apply(ConfigurableEditor.java:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.applyAndClose(SettingsDialog.java:197)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.doOKAction(SettingsDialog.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable$showDialog$dialog$1.doOKAction(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$OkAction.doAction(DialogWrapper.java:1881)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1834)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at com.chrisrm.idea.ui.MTButtonUI$ButtonHighlighter.mouseReleased(MTButtonUI.java:387)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.C
```

Answer (score 11):

This is an issue with the JDK version being too recent, as shown in this line:

```
CsvFileTypeOverrider: net/seesharpsoft/intellij/plugins/csv/CsvFileTypeOverrider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I had a similar bug where Gradle sync died immediately with the `Cause: invalid type code: 1C` error. Switching the JDK from OpenJDK 14 I installed to the integrated JDK that comes bundled with Android Studio fixed the issue.

To switch the JDK version, go to File > Project Structure, select "SDK Location" on the left sidebar, and under "JDK Location" select the dropdown arrow and then select `Embedded JDK: C:\Users\user\...`

[image: JDK location image]

Comment: I've go the same issue and this solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

New Java versions need new Gradle ones.
Go to Project Structure then change:

1. Plugin version to the newest stable one. [image]( Mine is 4.0.0 and 4.0.1).
2. Gradle Version to ...( Mine is 6.6.1).

That is all. It is fixed. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem. i try to change the version of gradle at project tab of dependences.but i ran to other problems .anyway maybe it will work for you

Comment: You can put this text in comments.